# If populated, UPDATE rather than INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am coding a CMS system (I am new to PHP) mainly to learn the language and I am getting stuck with a small INSERT if empty and UPDATE if a record already exists. I have a general_settings table which holds information about the website. I have one page called General Settings where you can insert data such as Site Title, Slogan, Logo etc. to the database.

However, if there is already data in the database, rather than INSERT another row, I want to UPDATE the current row... How would I do this? I am currently getting an error...

Upload Error:

```
INSERT INTO general_settings (company_logo, site_title, site_slogan, site_address, email_address) VALUES ('Company Logo', 'Site Title', 'Slogan', 'SITE ADDRESS', 'EMAIL@EMAIL.COM') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE general_settings set company_logo = 'Company Logo', site_title = 'Site Title', site_slogan = 'Slogan', site_address = 'SITE ADDRESS', email_address = 'EMAIL@EMAIL.COM'
```

which throws:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set company_logo = 'Company Logo', site_title = 'Site Title', site_slogan = 'Slo' at line 1

Page Code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "REMOVED";
    $password = "REMOVED";
    $dbname = "REMOVED";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    } 

    else {
        $company_logo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['company_logo']);
        $site_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['site_title']);
        $site_slogan = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['site_slogan']);
        $site_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['site_address']);
        $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email_address']);
        $Query = "INSERT INTO general_settings (company_logo, site_title, site_slogan, site_address, email_address) VALUES ('$company_logo', '$site_title', '$site_slogan', '$site_address', '$email_address') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE general_settings set company_logo = '$company_logo', site_title = '$site_title', site_slogan = '$site_slogan', site_address = '$site_address', email_address = '$email_address'";
        $conn->query($Query);
    }

    if ($conn->affected_rows <= 0){
        echo "Upload Error: <br><br> $Query <br><br>" . $conn->error;
        $conn->close();
    } 

    else {
        header ('location: /dashboard.php');
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col=value,col=value...`. No need for the table name or the `SET`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @uri2x, either post that as answer or ask OP to delete the question in order to remove it from open question list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the [`INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax, you should not specify the table name, nor the `SET` keyword. Therefore your query should be the following:

```
INSERT INTO general_settings
  (company_logo, site_title, site_slogan, site_address, email_address)
VALUES
  ('Company Logo', 'Site Title', 'Slogan', 'SITE ADDRESS', 'EMAIL@EMAIL.COM')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  company_logo = 'Company Logo', site_title = 'Site Title',
  site_slogan = 'Slogan', site_address = 'SITE ADDRESS', email_address = 'EMAIL@EMAIL.COM'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually have a key that's being updated in your query, th eprimary key (assuming it's auto-incremented and isn't being inserted manually) doesn't count.

```
ALTER TABLE general_settings ADD CONSTRAINT myawesomekey UNIQUE (company_logo, site_title, site_slogan, site_address, email_address)
```

You know, or something like that.